# Find and copy view dynamically in android?

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I have created a view now i just want to **copy** this one after another
say

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtComp1_Brand"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="ModelName"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkComp1GSB"
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxtNofISBCount"
        android:layout_width="80sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:textSize="8pt" >
    </EditText>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to copy this after one another dynamically in a linear layout say like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

how can i do this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and can add dynamically as well

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);

in loop 
LinearLayout child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
 // fill in any details dynamically here
  TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtComp1_Brand);
  textView.setText("text");
parent .addView(LinearLayout);
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe the keyword was COPY, not inflate.  Inflating is a rather expensive and time-consuming process, whereas copying is simple and quick.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<merge />` and/or `<include />`. See the Android Layout tips on reusing layouts in the Android SDK:

- [Layout Tricks: Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)
- [Layout Tricks: Merging Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Comment: Both links are dead.